# c++ inheritance question

Tags: c++, inheritance, explicit-constructor, rule-of-three

I have a question about this:

```
class A
{
  int a;
  int* pa;
public:
   A(int i):a(i) , pa(new int(a))
   {
      cout<<"A ctor"<<a<<endl;
   }
   ~A()
    {
      delete pa;
      cout<<"dtor\n";
    }
    int * &get()
    {
     return pa;
    }
};

class B : public A
{
     int b;
public:
      B (A obj): A(obj) , b(0)
      {
       cout<<"B ctor\n";
      }
      ~B()
      {
       cout<<"B dtor\n";
      }
};

int main()
{
 int i = 23 ; 
 A* p = new B(i);
}
```

Can tell me why the last line in `main` compiles? I pass an `int` into `B`'s constructor which expects an `A` object instead. I believe that the `int` is translated to an `A` in `B`'s constructor, but why?

Thanks in advance.

Avri.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have not declared `A` constructor as `explicit` compiler is creating an anomymous instance of `A` using `i` and using it to initialize `B` instance. If you don't want the compiler to do these implicit conversions declare your costructor as `explicit`. Then you will get a compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Because `A` has a single parameter constructor which takes an `int` and isn't marked `explicit` you can implicitly convert an `int` to an `A`.

When you do `new B(i)`, because the only viable constructor for `B` takes an `A`, an attempt is made to convert `i` to an `A` and construct the new `B` from that. This conversion is done by creating a temporary `A` using the constructor that takes an `int`.

When the `B` object is constructed, the base class `A` is copy constructed from the temporary `A` which means copying the member variables `a` and `pa` from the temporary `A`.

Strictly, because the constructor takes an `A` object by value, the temporary is, conceptually, copied again. The compiler may, however, eliminate the temporary by constructing the constructor parameter for `B` directly from `i` so the effect may well look like just a single copy.

This will cause a serious error because when the temporary `A` is destroyed, `delete pa` will cause the dynamically allocated `int` to be destroyed but the base class A of the newly allocated `B` object will still have a copy of this pointer which now no longer points at an invalid object. If the compiler doesn't eliminate one of the copies, a "double free" will happen immediately.

The key aspect of `A` is that it has a user-defined destructor that performs a resource action (deallocation). This is a strong warning that `A` needs a user-defined copy constructor and copy assignment operator because compiler generated version are likely not to work consistently with the design of `A`.

This is known as the "rule of three" which says that if you need a user-defined version of one of the destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator then you are likely to need user-defined versions of all of them.

Were you to attempt to free the dynamically allocated `B` object in your example, it would likely cause a "double free" error. In addition, `A`'s destructor would need to be marked as `virtual` for a delete through a pointer to `A` to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a conversion from `int` to `A`, implicitly your code is translated into

```
 A* p = new B(A(i));
```

Comment: great tnx , so for instance if i add instead of int other type such as char* the line wont compiled becasue A does not have appropriate c'tor to handle mentioned type.